# OPserver: SQL CPU Graph Not Displayed

Tags: stack-overflow, stackexchange-api, opserver

i am using opserver tool to monitor SQL performance everything works fine except  it is not display CPU graph sparks for both standalone and cluster

Comment: Welcome to SO. A bit more information about your configuration etc. might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i replace SQLCPUSpark function with this code

```
public ActionResult SQLCPUSpark(string node)
        {
            var instance = SQLInstance.Get(node);
            if (instance == null) 
                   return ContentNotFound("SQLNode not found with name = '" + node + "'");

            var dataPoints = instance.CPUHistoryLastHour;

            var chart = new Chart();
            var area = new ChartArea();
            area.AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
            area.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
            area.AxisY.Maximum = 100;

            // configure your chart area (dimensions, etc) here.
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

            // create and customize your data series.
            var series = new Series();
            foreach (var item in dataPoints.Data)
            {
                series.Points.AddXY(item.EventTime.ToOADate(), item.ProcessUtilization);
            }
            series.Label = "";
            series.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;
            chart.Series.Add(series);
            return chart.ToResult();
        }
```

Comment: If this was the solution to your problem, please mark it as answer, to help other persons with the same problem as yours